# Middle English Yogh character

Tags: fonts, packages, characters, typewriter

I was wondering if anyone knows of a package which supports the Middle English character yogh - that's Ȝ (U+021C) ȝ (U+021D). In TIPA, there is the character ezh - that's Ʒ (U+01B7) ʒ (U+0292). Ezh is very similar to yogh and is listed as yogh in TIPA, but I specifically need the Middle English letter used in transliterating runes. I could use XeTeX to simply insert the character using a different font, but since thorn (Þ (U+00DE) þ (U+00FE)) eth  (Ð (U+00D0) ð (U+00F0)) ash (Æ (U+00C6) æ (U+00E6)) and wynn (Ƿ (U+01F7) ƿ (U+01BF)) are all available, I was hoping to maintain consistency. I'd also really like to be able to typeset it in the typewriter text style as - so far, in the rest of my document - all transliterations have been typeset in that style.

Comment: What font are you using currently? I don't think this can be solved with a package, but only with an appropriate font. I use the [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/) font for Middle English, but this is a serifed font, and certainly not typewriter style. A quick check of the fonts on my system that have yogh finds that none are typewriter style (not very surprising, I think.)

Comment: Hi :) Well, I'm using the standard Computer Modern font for my transliterations. I'm basically trying to produce a document on Futhorc - the Old English Runic alphabet. For the runes, I do use Junicode, but I want to use Computer Modern, ideally, for the rest of the text and the transliterations. For the sake of constituency, I was hoping to stick with computer modern and was hoping there might be a package like TIPA for the IPA or textgreek for Greek, that would allow me to input the yogh in a computer modern style font.

Comment: There is metafont source for a CM-like Old English font on CTAN: [cmoefont](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cmoefont).

Comment: Thanks very much, I've found it :) I'm not quite sure how to install it though, I've run metafont on it, I think, but XeTeX can't seem to find it

Comment: Okay, I think I may need a bit of help installing fonts with metafont. I'm using ubuntu and I've tried putting the cmoefont folder in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/` as well as `~/texmf/tex/latex/` and I ran `mf` on cmoett10.mf as well as `mktexmf` in both directories, but I can't seem to make fontspec use either font. Furthermore, `mf` simply produces cmoett10.2062gf and a .log file and `mktexmf` doesn't seem to produce anything. Do you know how to install the font properly and get it working with XeTeX?

Comment: You can simply place the `.mf` files into the same folder as your `.tex` file and use them with `\newfont{\oerm}{cmoer10}` and `{\oerm D d T t G g n u}`. Note that this will render only the 10pt version of the font, if you want it at 12pt, try `\font\oermbig=cmoer10 scaled 1200` and use it with `{\oermbig …}` Also note that the font only contains above mentioned letters (as stated in the readme file). The 6 files with ending with `…10.mf` are the actual fonts you want. Also try consulting [http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/metafont/beginners/metafont-for-beginners.pdf]

Comment: @brian-ammon could you make that an answer please

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I expanded the answer a bit, to make the process a little clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) pointed out, there is **metafont source for a CM-like Old English font on CTAN**, which is called [**`cmoefont`**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cmoefont).

### Obtaining the fonts

Download the `.zip` from CTAN and place all of the resulting `.mf` files in the same directory as your `.tex` file. The actual font files are:

- `cmoebx10.mf` – Bold Extended 10 point
- `cmoer10.mf` – Roman 10 point
- `cmoesc10.mf` – Caps and Small Caps 10 point
- `cmoesl10.mf` – Slanted Roman 10 point
- `cmoeti10.mf` – Text Italic 10 point
- `cmoett10.mf` – Typewriter Text 10 point

### Loading the fonts

You now have two options to load these fonts into your document for usage (to me they seem like the TeX and LaTeX way, respectively):

1. Use the way described in [*MetaFont for Beginners*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/metafont/beginners/metafont-for-beginners.pdf) (4.4 “Using a New Font in TeX”):
   Declare a new font with `\font\oeroman=cmoer10`.
2. Use the way described in [*MetaFont – Generische Zeichenbeschreibung*](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/%7Epiefel/LaTeX-PS/V13-metafont.pdf) [german] (5 Einbindung in LaTeX):
   Use `\newfont{oeroman}{cmoer10}`.

As MetaFont renders the font for a specific size (or more correctly, resolution), the font used this way will be at 10 point and at 10 point only, even if your `\documentclass` option says differently. To get the correct size for a 12 point font size, for example, you need to tell MetaFont to scale up the font accordingly with `scaled 1200` so you can use either of these commands to load your font:

```
\font\oeromantwelve=cmoer10 scaled 1200
\newfont{\oeromantwelve}{cmoer10 scaled 1200}
```

Or, even more complicated:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmoer10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n}{<-> cmoer10}{}
```

Where `<->` seems to be an option for automatic scaling, and more information about these parameters can be found in the [*MetaFont book*](http://www.math.zju.edu.cn/ligangliu/latexforum/texbooks/metafont/metafontbook.pdf).

LaTeX will use the information you provide to run `mktextfm` on the MetaFont sources to create font metrics (`.tfm`) and a GF font (cf. *MetaFont for Beginners:* 4.5 “Magnification (and Resolution)” for more information on this).

### Using the fonts

To finally use the fonts in your document, you may use:

```
{\oeroman D d T t G g n u}
{\oeromantwelve D d T t G g n u}
{\usefont{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n} D d T t G g n u}
```

The latter one only for the last loading method.

---

### Caveats

The fonts contain *only* the following letters (cf. Readme):

```
D  capital eth           Ð
d  eth                   ð
T  capital thorn         Þ
t  thorn                 þ
G  capital yogh          Ȝ
g  yogh                  ȝ
n  Polish ogonek accent  ˛
```

The roman derived  fonts (i. e. not `cmoeti10`) also have

```
u  lower-case thorn with side bowl pointing top right
```

---

From my point of view, full unicode input (and output) is superior in this case, although you would obviously have to change your font in this case. Take a look at the fonts suggested by the MUFI (Medieval Unicode Font Initiative): [MUFI font page](http://folk.uib.no/hnooh/mufi/fonts/index.html).