# Rendering Capital Wynn

Tags: fonts, languages

Gentium is supposed to have support for capital wynn but I'm unsure of what font encoding I need to use in order to get it to show up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\newcommand{\w}{\textwynn}
\newcommand{\W}{^^c7^^b7}
\usepackage{gentium}
\begin{document}
\W
\end{document}
```

I'm not attached to Gentium at all, so if that is the issue here I'll gladly change to another font. Also I can't use xeLatex. Is there any hope of getting this to work?

Comment: are you attached to pdftex or is luatex a possibility?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111032/middle-english-yogh-character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glyph is in the type1-font (the afm-file shows an entry `uni01F7`) but as far as I can it is nowhere encoded, so to use it you would have to create a tfm and an enc-file and some more support files.

With lualatex or xelatex it works directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium}
\begin{document}
 ^^^^01f7 \symbol{"01F7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I figured there is no hope of pdfTex worfking without some serious work.