# How to write abbreviated "the" as thorn with superscript e?

Tags: symbols

Ideally without using any external packages. I am looking for something like this.

[image: Middle English þ with superscript e]
[image: Early modern y with superscript e]

For more about the letter, read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)).

Comment: Why not includegraphics it?

Comment: I've never used that outside of the figure environment and that just seems against the TeX spirit of typesetting honestly.

Comment: Well, the "proper" way would be to create a font file (if it's pdflatex must be METAFONT, otherwise can use TrueType font) that contains the glyph, then typeset that character... anyway where (which font) does that character come from?

Comment: Checkout the edit.

Comment: Look, even Wikipedia use an inline image to display the character. You probably don't want to create custom font file just for this

Comment: I was hoping for a way where some type of gothic `y` and `e` could have been amalgamated into a decent depiction?

Comment: Maybe it's possible, but let's see if someone want to do that...

Comment: How important is your precise choice of fonts?

Comment: I have already required `amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amscd` and am using `lmodern`. I'd like to avoid importing a new font just for this but I mean... some solution is better than no solution?

Comment: I meant: several symbol fonts (such as wasy or tipa) have the thorn symbol included, but they don't look like the particular rendering you showed in your question. How important to you is it to have that _look_ to the character, or are you happy with just any thorn symbol with a superscript e?

Comment: Also: `amsthm` and `amscd` do not define new fonts.

Comment: An alternative, since your base font is `lmodern`, you can use the computer modern old English font described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111032/middle-english-yogh-character which will fit pretty well stylistically.

Comment: I am happy with any though I'll end up selecting the solution that looks the closest.

Comment: thorn is `\th` so the most direct answer for thorn with superscript e is `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\begin{document}\th\textsuperscript{e}\end{document}` but is that what you want?

Comment: If you have an OpenType/TrueType/Graphite/AAT font that supports this, you can use it with `fontspec` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine `lmodern` with the old English font `cmoefont`.

[image]

Step 1: follow the instructions in [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111032/middle-english-yogh-character) to obtain `cmoefont` and drop all the files in the same director as your `tex` file.

Step 2: load the font files and use it. The above image is, for example, generated by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmoer10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n}{<-> cmoer10}{}
\newcommand{\THE}{{\usefont{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n} u}\textsuperscript{e}}

\begin{document}
The \THE\ the olde 
\end{document}
```

---

A slightly more complicated version, using `stackengine`, can get the superscript `e` higher up similar to your examples.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmoer10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n}{<-> cmoer10}{}
\newcommand{\THE}{{\usefont{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n} u}\textsuperscript{e}}
\newcommand{\oTHE}{\stackengine{-0.3ex}{\usefont{OT1}{cmoer10}{m}{n} u}{~e}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}

\begin{document}
The \THE\ the olde  \oTHE 
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is a thorn (`\th`) in the standard T1 encoded latin modern

Comment: *what*! I didn't know that. @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as @Willie Wong's answer but with `QTCloisteredMonk` as the font and different spacing in `stackengine`. Compile with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{QTCloisteredMonk}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{QTCloisteredMonk}{m}{n}{<-> QTCloisteredMonk}{}
\newcommand{\THE}{\stackon[0pt]{\usefont{OT1}{QTCloisteredMonk}{m}{n} y}{\usefont{OT1}{QTCloisteredMonk}{m}{n}\kern.06em\tiny e}}

\begin{document}
Early the: \THE
\end{document}
```